# When is swallowing fish bones dangerous

Tags: digestion, fish, injury

According to a study <sup>([2013](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26767418))</sup> fish bone ingestion by young kids is rather common.

Also, in some extremely rare cases the bone can penetrate the digestive tract and end up in other organs <sup>([2015](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26634168))</sup>.

---

Fish bones come in various sizes, hardness etc. Eating fish would inevitably result in swallowing them. Although I assume small fish like [sardines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sardine) shouldn't be much of a problem, bones from bigger fish can potentially be dangerous.

When would swallowing a fish-bone be a problem? (e.g. can cause injury in any part of the digestive system) Would the stomach dissolve partially or completely some fish-bones?

Also, are there any differences in whether a kid or an adult swallowed it?

Comment: Stomach acid will help to prevent problems by making the bone less sharp. Only a small amount from the exterior surface of the bone needs to dissolve to make it blunt.

Comment: @CountIblis I don't think making it blunt would make it much less dangerous. Especially big bones like the one in the 2015 study i linked ([image of bone during operation](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4655044/figure/fig1/)).

Comment: I agree, but then there is of course a gag reflex that would normally prevent one from swallowing bones that are too big. So, normally, the bones you can swallow are not going to be a problem; at least I would guess that half a billion years of fine tuning of the body plan via natural selection has led to a solution of the most obvious problems.